# Flink for embedded stream processing in OSGi

Tags: osgi, apache-flink

I would like to use Apache Flink to process event inside an application.
My tests on a standalone JVM worked reasonably well though flink is a really big dependency.

I also tried to get it running in OSGi but gave up for now because of the many dependencies.

So my question is:
How small can I make Flink. I currently tried with the maven dependency on flink-streaming-java.

Unfortunately this depends on or embeds (only listing the questionable ones):

- flink-shaded-hadoop2
- kryo
- zookeeper
- netty
- jetty
- apache http client
- apache http core
- scala
- akka
- jackson

It also looks like several jars embed the same libs again and again. Like some google libs and asm.

So is there some way to get a slimmmer version of flink for local usage that does not depend on so many libs?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the dependencies are required for Apache Flink's primary use-cases namely, distributed stream and batch processing.

- Zookeeper for high-availability in case of (process) failures
- Netty for data network transfer
- Jetty for monitoring via REST API and web dashboard
- Akka (and transitively Scala) for coordination of distributed processes

Most of these libraries are tightly coupled with the system and cannot be easily switched off or excluded.

I am sorry, there is no stripped down version for local stream processing.

Comment: Is there any more suitable library?